# Python: Converting bytearray to bytestring weird results

Tags: python, arrays, byte

I'm appending the number 33 to a bytearray, which works fine but when I am converting the bytearray to a bytestring the number 33 converts to an exclamation mark (!).

Example Code below:

```
f_bytes = bytearray(b"\xFF\xFF")

f_bytes.append(3)
f_bytes.append(33)
f_bytes.append(12)

byte_msg = bytes(f_bytes)

print(byte_msg)
print (''.join(format(x, '02x') for x in f_bytes))
```

Here is the output:

```
b'\xff\xff\x03!\x0c'
ffff03210c
```

I am expecting the bytestring to look like the bytearray but it doesn't, can someone help me understand the problem?

Comment: Do you know the ASCII code for `!`? In hexadecimal?

Comment: The ASCII code for ! is 33 but I don't know why its appending the exclamation mark and not just the number

Comment: A true expert can probably give a better answer, but the Python [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function takes its arguments and calls `str()` on them. Apparently, when Python stringifies bytes, its selects the most compact visual representation possible for the printable ASCII characters. For example, if you add `65` to your byte array, you'll see `A` when it gets stringified. Python could have selected a different convention, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `0x00`-`0x1f`, `0x7F` and `0xFF` of the ASCII table are control characters which control the input/ output of a terminal. They are usually not printed in a non-binary string representation (on your shell they might appear as something like `^C`, `^M` or `^[[C` ..). In contrast to the other bytes `0x33` corresponds to the a literal which is printed in the string. In your second `print` command you disable the conversion into the exclamation mark literal by using a format string, thus you get the hexadecimal value for all bytes.